# Extract data and transpose in Python

Tags: python, extract, delimiter, csv

I have a text file from which I extracted a region between two strings. The extracted region looks like this:

```
title   "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" 
number  "G1"    "G2"    "G3"    "G4"    "G5"    "G6"
data "aaa,bbb"  "sss,ddd"   "fff,ggg"   "rrr,eee"   "aaa,ooo"   "ggg,aaa"
```

I'd like to write to a csv file. But even after specifying "\t" as delimiter, it's splitting near commas into separate cells in a row and tabs to get data into new lines something like this:

```
title   
"A" 
"B" 
"C" 
"D" 
"E" 
"F" 
number  
"G1"    
"G2"    
"G3"    
"G4"    
"G5"    
"G6"
data 
"aaa    bbb"    
"sss    ddd"    
"fff    ggg"    
"rrr    eee"    
"aaa    ooo"    
"ggg    aaa"
```

I need it this way:

```
title   A   B   C   D   E   F   
number  G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6
data    aaa,bbb sss,ddd fff,ggg rrr,eee aaa,ooo ggg,aaa
```

in separate cells in a row, delimited by tab. I appreciate any help.

Comment: `The extracted region looks like this` <- Do you have this extracted region in a list/string/file/...?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget It is currently in a file. I used `if line.startswith ("!Sample_title"):
            copy = True
            outfile.write(line)` to write in a file.

Answer (score 0):

infile.csv:

```
title   "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" 
number  "G1"    "G2"    "G3"    "G4"    "G5"    "G6"
data    "aaa,bbb"   "sss,ddd"   "fff,ggg"   "rrr,eee"   "aaa,ooo"   "ggg,aaa"
```

outfile.csv:

```
title   A   B   C   D   E   F   
number  G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6
data    aaa,bbb sss,ddd fff,ggg rrr,eee aaa,ooo ggg,aaa
```

Code:

```
In [40]: import csv

In [41]: with open('infile.csv') as infile, open('outfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
   ....:     writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
   ....:     for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"'):
   ....:         writer.writerow(row)
   ....:
```

Answer (score 0):

using regex

```
f=open('yoyr_file.txt','r')
f=f.readlines()
for x in f:
    print " ".join(re.findall('\w+,?\w*',x))
```

output:

```
'title A B C D E F'
'number G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6'
'data aaa,bbb sss,ddd fff,ggg rrr,eee aaa,ooo ggg,aaa'
```

`readlines()` will read your files as list of lines, then i am looping over it to find the pattern. when you get the pattern you can format it like whatever you want.